# Application.GetResourceStream is ignored?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, embedded-resource

I have a silly problem, that I'm sure someone will spot in a second. Anyways, I am trying to test some write/read stream options for a Windows Phone 7 Game application. After some searching I found out `FileStream` operations are not allowed with Windows Phone 7, and instead I should use tools like `Application.GetResourceStream`, and `IsolatedStorageFile`.

What I did for the testing was I created a new Phone 7 Game app(4.0) project, and I changed  game1.cs.

I added some needed references:

```
using System.IO ;
using System.Windows.Resources ;
using System.Windows ;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage ;
```

And also added the 1.txt, and 2.txt files to my project for the file reading/writing actions(didn't come that far though yet). Using some tutorials on the web I wrote some small piece of code in the game1 constructor that includes some reading/writing from/to the txt files. I added some breakpoints in visual studio 2010, as I like to see the things one by one before I move to the next part. Anyways what happens, is that project compiles without any errors, but when I run it nothing happens. The debuger doesn't even stop at the breakpoints. I also get no errors whatsoever, which is why I'm stuck. I tried to comment all the lines, and check one by one, and it seems this line is what messes it up:

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri("1.txt", UriKind.Relative));
```

Can anyone direct me to the source of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What is the `Build` type set to for `1.txt`? It should be set to `Content` if you are going to use `Application.GetResourceStream`.

In addition, try using the full syntax for application resources:

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri("/Project.Name;component/1.txt", UriKind.Relative));
```

The path, after "component" should match the path from the root of the project. For example, if it is in the "Data/Text" folder it should be "/Project.Name;component/Data/Text/1.txt")